# Metadata dll file is missing

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I was having problems with AppResource files (*ResXFileCodeGenerator failed to produce an output for input file*).

I manually deleted the `bin` and `obj` folders of all the projects of my Xamarin.Forms Solution as cleaning the Solution didn't work.

Now I'm getting the following errors when building the solution again:

> Error CS0006  Metadata file 'C:\Users\Costas\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\ref\MyApp.dll' could not be
> found MyApp.Android   C:\Users\Costas\source\repos\My
> App\MyApp\MyApp.Android\CSC   1   Active

> Error CS0006  Metadata file 'C:\Users\Costas\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\MyApp.dll' could not be
> found MyApp.iOS   C:\Users\Costas\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.iOS\CSC  1   Active

> Error XFC0000 Cannot resolve type
> "AppResources".   MyApp   C:\Users\Costas\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\MainPage.xaml    26

Is there any way to make the project Build again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `AppResources` type issue was unrelated. I hadn't include the namespace in the XAML file.

The .dll issue resolved after trying to Deploy the project and run it on the Android emulator.

For some reason build was constantly failing. Deploy worked at the first try.

Comment: *"For some reason build was constantly failing."* In Build / Configuration Manager, UNCHECK iOS build. (Checkmark it again when you need it.) Probably it was attempting to build both platforms. Deploy knows which platform you are deploying to. `Android project / rt-click / build` is another way to build only for Android.

Comment: Yes. If you look at the errors one is Android related and the other iOS related. After Deploying for the Android emulator though, I can now hit Build and both errors have vanished, including the iOS one.

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT Just tried, but there is a time restriction. I will mark it as a solution as soon as I am able to. (2 hours left now.)